# Matlab - The second derivative

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, derivative

I am working on some problems surrounding velocity, acceleration, etc, involving curve fitting, interpolation etc, from given data points. I am in need of finding the second derivative, acceleration, given time and distance points. I am currently finding the velocity using the following code, after doing a cubic fit with 100 points.

```
time = [0:12];
altitude =  [0,107.37,210.00,307.63,400.00,484.60,550.00,583.97,580.00,549.53,...
570.00,699.18,850];

newTime = linspace(0,12,100);
rcubic = polyfit(time,altitude,3);
vrcubic = polyval(rcubic,newTime);

velocity = polyval(polyder(rcubic),newTime);
```

However when I apply the same formula to try and get acceleration, code below, I get answers in the order of power 110

```
acceleration = polyval(polyder(velocity,newTime));
```

Am I not finding velocity correctly, or is my method for acceleration wrong, and if so how do I solve it.

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) if it is solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your method for the calculation of acceleration may be wrong. You used `polyder` correctly when calculating velocity, but not the acceleration. To obtain the acceleration you would need to apply the polynomial derivative twice:

```
time = [0:12];
altitude =  [0,107.37,210.00,307.63,400.00,484.60,550.00,583.97,580.00,549.53,...
570.00,699.18,850];

newTime = linspace(0,12,100);
rcubic = polyfit(time, altitude, 3);
vrcubic = polyval(rcubic, newTime);

figure;
hold on;
plot(time, altitude);
plot(newTime, vrcubic);

velocity = polyval(polyder(rcubic), newTime);
plot(newTime, velocity)

acceleration = polyval(polyder(polyder(rcubic)), newTime);

plot(newTime, acceleration)

legend('original', 'poly', 'velocity poly', 'acceleration poly');
```